# munin 404 after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, apache2.4, munin

I've upgraded my Ubuntu Server from 12.04.3 (or maybe it was .4 - don't really remember) to 14.04 (now it's 14.04.1) some time ago. Didn't need to use munin since then. Now I need it, but all I'm getting is a `404 error` while trying to load. Apaches logs show only this:

```
192.168.1.1 - - [19/Oct/2014:19:41:21 +0200] "GET /munin HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36"
```

Can anyone help me to make it work again ? (It worked flawlessly on 12.04)

Comment: Did you reinstall it since you upgraded?  I don't actually know anything about it, but it's not a standard Ubuntu program, I don't think.

Comment: No I didn't. And that's the last thing I want to do, since I've configured it about 5 years ago, and don't remember now which plugins I've changed and what was changed in them (and it took me a week to get all those customized plugins to work properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the Munin upgrade is borked. It leaves /etc/apache2/conf.d/munin (softlinks to /etc/munin/apache.conf) in the now unused conf.d folder.

Move your softlink into the new folder
`mv /etc/apache2/conf.d/munin /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`

This will still die, but for another reason. Apache 2.2 -> Apache 2.4 upgrade, which no longer uses `Order allow,deny` and `Allow from .....`

Find all the above in `/etc/munin/apache.conf` and do something like this:

### Old values

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1
```

### New values

```
Require local
```

If you actually want to access it from some other network, eg, 192.168.0.0/24 then replace it with this:

### New values

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
```

That should get you working.