# The requested URL /munin/ was not found on this server after 14.04 upgrade

Tags: server, apache2, munin

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12 to 14.04 my Munin setup stopped working.

I tried following the advice given here

[munin 404 after upgrading to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539064/munin-404-after-upgrading-to-14-04)

reloaded and restartet apache, restartet munin and munin-node - but still no success.

Here are my config files:

/etc/munin/apache.conf

```
Alias /munin /var/cache/munin/www
<Directory /var/cache/munin/www>
        # Updated conf to apache 2.4 standard https://askubuntu.com/questions/539064/munin-404-after-upgrading-to-14-04
        Require local
        Require MYIP1
        Require MYIP2
        # Options None

        # This file can be used as a .htaccess file, or a part of your apache
        # config file.
        #
        # For the .htaccess file option to work the munin www directory
        # (/var/cache/munin/www) must have "AllowOverride all" or something
        # close to that set.
        #

        # AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd
        # AuthName "Munin"
        # AuthType Basic
        # require valid-user

        # This next part requires mod_expires to be enabled.
        #

        # Set the default expiration time for files to 5 minutes 10 seconds from
        # their creation (modification) time.  There are probably new files by
        # that time.
        #

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault M310
    </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

/etc/munin/munin.conf

```
# Example configuration file for Munin, generated by 'make build'

# The next three variables specifies where the location of the RRD
# databases, the HTML output, logs and the lock/pid files.  They all
# must be writable by the user running munin-cron.  They are all
# defaulted to the values you see here.
#
# dbdir /var/lib/munin
# htmldir /var/cache/munin/www
# logdir /var/log/munin
# rundir  /var/run/munin
#
# Where to look for the HTML templates
tmpldir /etc/munin/templates

# (Exactly one) directory to include all files from.
#
includedir /etc/munin/munin-conf.d

# Make graphs show values per minute instead of per second
#graph_period minute

# Graphics files are normaly generated by munin-graph, no matter if
# the graphs are used or not.  You can change this to
# on-demand-graphing by following the instructions in
# http://munin.projects.linpro.no/wiki/CgiHowto
#
#graph_strategy cgi

# munin-cgi-graph is invoked by the web server up to very many times at the
# same time.  This is not optimal since it results in high CPU and memory
# consumption to the degree that the system can thrash.  Again the default is
# 6.  Most likely the optimal number for max_cgi_graph_jobs is the same as
# max_graph_jobs.
#
#munin_cgi_graph_jobs 6

# If the automatic CGI url is wrong for your system override it here:
#
#cgiurl_graph /cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph

# munin-graph runs in parallel, the number of concurrent processes is
# 6.  If you want munin-graph to not be parallel set to 0.  If set too
# high it will slow down munin-graph.  Some experiments are needed to
# determine how many are optimal on your system.  On a multi-core
# system with good SCSI disks the number can probably be quite high.
#
#max_graph_jobs 6

# Drop somejuser@fnord.comm and anotheruser@blibb.comm an email everytime
# something changes (OK -> WARNING, CRITICAL -> OK, etc)
#contact.someuser.command mail -s "Munin notification" somejuser@fnord.comm
#contact.anotheruser.command mail -s "Munin notification" anotheruser@blibb.comm
#
# For those with Nagios, the following might come in handy. In addition,
# the services must be defined in the Nagios server as well.
#contact.nagios.command /usr/bin/send_nsca nagios.host.comm -c /etc/nsca.conf

# a simple host tree
[my.host1.com]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes

[my.host2.com]
    address 10.1.1.23
    use_node_name yes

[my.host3.com]
    address 10.1.1.24
    use_node_name yes

#
# A more complex example of a host tree
#
## First our "normal" host.
# [fii.foo.com]
#       address foo
#
## Then our other host...
# [fay.foo.com]
#       address fay
#
## Then we want totals...
# [foo.com;Totals] #Force it into the "foo.com"-domain...
#       update no   # Turn off data-fetching for this "host".
#
#   # The graph "load1". We want to see the loads of both machines...
#   # "fii=fii.foo.com:load.load" means "label=machine:graph.field"
#       load1.graph_title Loads side by side
#       load1.graph_order fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#
#   # The graph "load2". Now we want them stacked on top of each other.
#       load2.graph_title Loads on top of each other
#       load2.dummy_field.stack fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load2.dummy_field.draw AREA # We want area instead the default LINE2.
#       load2.dummy_field.label dummy # This is needed. Silly, really.
#
#   # The graph "load3". Now we want them summarised into one field
#       load3.graph_title Loads summarised
#       load3.combined_loads.sum fii.foo.com:load.load fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load3.combined_loads.label Combined loads # Must be set, as this is
#                                                 # not a dummy field!
#
## ...and on a side note, I want them listen in another order (default is
## alphabetically)
#
# # Since [foo.com] would be interpreted as a host in the domain "com", we
# # specify that this is a domain by adding a semicolon.
# [foo.com;]
#       node_order Totals fii.foo.com fay.foo.com
#
```

The munin files are present in /var/cache/munin/www. Any ideas on where to go from here are much appreciated.